# Uncommon problem on xdvipdfmx in macTeX?

Tags: xetex, texlive, mactex, xdvipdfmx

When I use the following code to type Chinese text in TeXShop of macTeX[image]It reports an error

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test_zh.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.st
y) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg))
*************************************************
* xeCJK warning: "fandol"
* 
* Fandol is being set as the default font for CJK text.
* Please make sure it has been properly installed.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'FandolSong-Regular' does not contain script 'CJK'.
*************************************************
(./test_zh.aux) [1]sh: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin/xdvipdfmx: No such file 
or directory
(./test_zh.aux)Broken pipe
```

I am so confused now QAQ.Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome! I have the impression that your TeX installation is broken, but the issue might depend on the file name: are you using Chinese characters or spaces in the file name?

Comment: Does it mean that the tex file lay in the Chinese characters or spaces?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The file can contain spaces and Chinese characters, of course. I was talking about the file *name*. What's it? It's difficult to interpret from the image.

Comment: I don't think I use Chinese characters or spaces in the file name. I just use "test_zh.tex"?

Comment: OK, can you run `xelatex` from the terminal?

Comment: It does not work. I even change the code in test_zh.tex to
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello,\LaTeX!
\end{document}

Comment: What's the output of the terminal command `type xdvipdfmx`?

Comment: Should I use the command "xelatex type xdvipdfmx"? The output is "This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `type'.
<*> type 
         xdvipdfmx
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: "

Comment: No, just `type xdvipdfmx`

Comment: I think whether I misunderstand something. If I use "type xdvipdfmx" directly in terminal, it shows "-bash: type: xdvipdfmx: not found"

Comment: That means that your TeX installation is broken.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` run in Terminal Return?

Comment: It shows "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/lujinliang/anaconda3/bin:/Users/lujinliang/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/mysql/bin"

Comment: Should I reload macTeX?